# getting ' Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export' when running karma

Tags: angular, webpack, karma-runner, chai

while running the karma test cases, I am able to get  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
 error. below is the code snippet of the karma.config.js file -- Please help us, we are breaking our heads around this from long time...

```
process.env.BABEL_ENV = "test"

module.exports = function(config) {
config.set({

// base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
basePath: '',

// frameworks to use
// available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
frameworks: ['mocha','chai'],


// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: ['node_modules/angular/angular.js',
'node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
'app/**/*.js',
'app/**/*.spec.js'],
webpackMiddleware: {noInfo:true},

// list of files to exclude
exclude: [
],

// preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
// available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
preprocessors:{'app/**/*.js':['webpack'],'app/**/*.spec.js':['webpack']},
  babelPreprocessor: {
        options: {
            "presets": ["es2015"],
            "plugins": ["transform-es2015-modules-umd"]
        }
    },

   webpack :{ 
        devtool: 'inline-source-map',
        module: {

            loaders: [
                /* add the appropriate loaders */
                /* almost the same as the webpack.config */
                {test: /\.json$/,loader: "json-loader"},
                { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'raw' },
                { test: /\.styl$/, loader: 'style!css!stylus' },
                { test: /\.css/, loader: 'style!css' },
                { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel-loader',
                 include:['app/**/*.js','app/**/*.spec.js'],
                 exclude: ['node_modules'] }
            ]
        }

    },
// test results reporter to use
// possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
// available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
reporters: ['progress', 'coverage'],
coverageReporter: {
    reporters:[
        {type:'lcov', dir:'coverage/',subdir:'.'},
        {type:'json', dir:'coverage/',subdir:'.'},
        {type:'text-summary'}
    ]
},
// web server port
port: 9876,

// enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
colors: true,

// level of logging
// possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

// enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
autoWatch: true,

// start these browsers
// available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
browsers: ['Chrome'],

// Continuous Integration mode
// if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
singleRun: false,

// Concurrency level
// how many browser should be started simultanous
concurrency: Infinity,
plugins:[
  require('karma-webpack'),('karma-babel-preprocessor'),
  ('karma-chai'),
  ('karma-mocha'),
  ('karma-coverage'),
  ('karma-chrome-launcher')
]
})
}
```

Comment: could you share the full error message please?

Comment: it's possible that you will need to require the babel-register module at the start of your tests